# no calculation trough html>servlet>bean and bean>jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have a DynamicWebApp in Eclipse with Tomcat Apache.

My task: The bean consists of 2 operands of type Integer and as text the arithmetic operations Addition with '+', Subtraction with '-' and Multiplication with 'MUL'. The bean returns the calculation result of type Integer. Then implement the following two scenarios:

Scenario 1: Implement a suitable Java Servlet that calls the Java Bean. You call the servlet using your own HTML page.
Scenario 2: Implement a suitable Java server page that reuses the Java bean using JSP standard actions. Then call your bean from the JSP page.

html opens and i can calculate. after submit nothing opens but i can see in the browser url what i wrote.
and if i start the jsp than i get: cannot find any information on property (firstNum) in a bean of type (bean.CalculatorBean)

my html code called: **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hallo Welt</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="HalloServlet" method="get" style="text-align: center">
        <table border="1" width="25%">
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                <td colspan="2">Rechner</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zahl 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstNum"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Operator</td>
                <td><select name="operator">
                        <option value="+">+</option>
                        <option value="-">-</option>
                        <option value="*">MUL</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Zahl 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="secondNum"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="="></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet called: **HalloServlet.java**

```
package calculator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import bean.CalculatorBean;

@WebServlet("/HalloServlet")
public class HalloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        // Get Parameter from index.html
        int operand1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("firstNum"));
        int operand2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("secondNum"));
        char operator1 = request.getParameter("operator").charAt(0);

        // Parameter from HalloServlet.java to CalculatorBean
        CalculatorBean.setFirstNum(operand1);
        CalculatorBean.setSecondNum(operand2);
        CalculatorBean.setOperator(operator1);

        // Parameter from CalculatorBean to HalloServlet.java
        CalculatorBean.getFirstNum();
        CalculatorBean.getSecondNum();
        CalculatorBean.getOperator();

        int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("result"));
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(i);
        out.flush();

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    }

}
```

bean called: **CalculatorBean.java**

```
package bean;

public class CalculatorBean {
    private int firstNum;
    private int secondNum;
    private char operator = '+';
    private int result;

    public static void getFirstNum() {
    }

    public static void setFirstNum(int firstNum) {
    }

    public static void getSecondNum() {
    }

    public static void setSecondNum(int secondNum) {
    }

    public static void getOperator() {
    }

    public static void setOperator(char operator) {
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void calculate() {
        switch (this.operator) {
        case '+': {
            this.result = this.firstNum + this.secondNum;
            break;
        }
        case '-': {
            this.result = this.firstNum - this.secondNum;
            break;
        }
        case '*': {
            this.result = this.firstNum * this.secondNum;
            break;
        }
        }
    }

}
```

jsp called: **HalloJSP.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <jsp:useBean id="CalculatorBean" class="bean.CalculatorBean">
    </jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:setProperty name="CalculatorBean" property="*" />
    <%
        CalculatorBean.calculate();
    %>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br /> Ergebnis:
    <jsp:getProperty name="CalculatorBean" property="firstNum" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="CalculatorBean" property="operator" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="CalculatorBean" property="secondNum" />
    =
    <jsp:getProperty name="CalculatorBean" property="result" />

    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
    <form action="HalloJSP.jsp" method="post" style="text-align: center">
        <table border="1" width="25%">
            <tr style="text-align: center">
                <td colspan="2">Rechner</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zahl 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstNum"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Operator</td>
                <td><select name="operator">
                        <option value="+">+</option>
                        <option value="-">-</option>
                        <option value="*">MUL</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Zahl 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="secondNum"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="="></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>hallowelt</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Which version of Apache Tomcat? What have you tried so far? Did it include opening the web browser console and checking the network panel for error codes and responses from the server (it should have)?

Comment: I have the version 9.0 in apache. actually the jsp called the bean before and did my bill. But I think after I coded servlet the problems started. i'm not sure if i coded wrong or have connection problems. i get only: served at: /hallowelt but not the result. i get only a 500 failure

Answer (score -1):

You should have noticed that your implementation contains empty methods?

```
public static void setFirstNum (int firstNum) {
}
```

Best to create new bean! Right click on "src" or beanpackage.
Then click New -> Class. Give the bean a name and click on "add" at interface. In the following window enter "Serializable" and add purple serializable interface ...

Create attributes. mark this, right click -> source -> generate getter and setter!

Implement an empty constructor such as `CalcBean () {}`
implement in the setResult calculator. everything else is superfluous

**servlet**

do right click on your source folder or httpservlet package -> new -> servlet. name it -> click on doGet and make doPost -> Finito ... copy your stuff from open script "2 java servlets.pdf" necessarily via pdf-Reader! Go to page 23.
Mark the whole flow within the doGet method COMPLETE. Put that in your servlet. Replace the getter methods of your bean with:

```
o.println ("<p> number 1:" + beans.getFirstNummero () ...
```

open script in pdf reader, because then the formatting is inserted correctly formatted when "inserting" the script copy (therefore do not open pdf via browser, otherwise haste a single line when inserting)

What surprised me is that many have answered many, even though you have more code and almost everything completely specified and the error regarding the bean everyone should have noticed here ...

In the future, be a bit more curious while working in Eclipse ... everywhere, make a right-click and see what eclipse can do. Via plugins goes even more, but meanwhile Eclipse in contrast to android studio is better. that android studio is more intended for android code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).